# Should I put email address or Account name in SentOnBehalfofName?

Tags: outlook, mailitem

I am writing a program to allow user to send email from Exchange Shared Mailbox or "Send on behalf Of". I am planning to use MailItem.SentOnBehalfofName to do that.

Example:
Shared Mail box name - name "Test Shared mailbox"
Shared mailbox Email address - "test@mycompany.com"

But what should I put in SentOnBehalfofName property ? Should I put email address of shared mailbox ? Or Shared mailbox name ?

Also, for "Send on behalf of" faeture, should I put email address or user name in that MailItem.SentOnBehalfofName property ?

Thanks !

Comment: I'd say the name of the shared mailbox. 

"Flight Time: Sent on behalf of 'Corporate Travel'."

That said, I don't think this question is relevant to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever gets **uniquely** resolved to the corresponding GAL entry. If you type the name in the To edit box in an email and it gets successfully resolved without an ambiguous prompt, it will work for the `SentOnBehalfofName` property.